# How to insert characters between two different characters with sed

Tags: bash, sed

In markdown files, I have strings like `[can-be-anything](./can-be-any#vitedevserver)` and I want to change them to `[can-be-anything](./can-be-any.html#vitedevserver)`.

I want to insert `.html` before `#`.

I tried following but it doesn't work.

```
link=$(sed -e 's/.*](\.\/\(.*\)#.*/\1/g' $file)
sed -i "s|](./\(.*\)#|](./${link}.html#|g" $file
```

The first one to get `can-be-any` and second one to insert with `.html`.

How can I do this using Bash and sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
echo '[can-be-anything](./can-be-any#vitedevserver)' | sed 's/](\(\.\/.*\)#/](\1.html#/'
```

Comment: Since they are markdown files, I need to find a patter, ](./ and #. Otherwise it will insert .html to all #.

Comment: @shin updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @shin I had tried your command and seems to work for me. I don't know if your problem might be `.`. In `sed` using a `.` represents any character so if you want to specify the `.` character you should escape it by using: `\.`.

Comment: However using a `\.`  or `.` should have the same effect in this case. I think you have more strings whose look like this: `'[can-be-anything](@/can-be-any#vitedevserver)'`. Instead of `.` you have any other character.

Comment: Yes, there are strings in front of [can-be-anything].